# To use a data region in a list, the list must have group expressions?

Tags: c#, reporting, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Q:

I'm trying to control the visibility of the report sections.So I use a List.Each list will contain :

- A text box as a title for this section.
- A Table for the data.

If the Table has no rows ,I will hide the list.

After assigning the data source name to the list and to the table.

and trying to run. I get the following error.

> The table ‘.....’ is in a list that has no group expressions defined
>   for it.
>        To use a data region in a list, the list must have group
>   expressions.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dummy grouping to the list.

Right click the list

Select properties

In the General tab click "Edit Details Group"

In the Group on expression write: **=""**

Comment: hmmm , thanks a lot, the error has disappeared,but the list is hidden!!although the table has rows .
The visibility of the list is `=IIf(CountRows()=0,False,true)`

Comment: The visibility controls when the list is hidden. So TRUE means hide. In your expression when rows=0 you show the list and when>0 you hide it. You have to reverse true with false.

Comment: Please , can u clarify why this error has appeared, i wanna to know the reason?

Comment: List's are used to group data in a report, so reporting services require at least one group to exist. You can overcome this limitation by using a dummy expression like ="" or =0 etc

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask, it's better to undestand the solution, than copy-paste and use it.