# Why "PageBreakAtEnd = True" doesn't work in my report?

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, page-break

Q:

I make a report this report is long enough ,so i decided to break it in four pages.

When i set the `PageBreakAtEnd = True` property For The list , i wanna to be the last one in the page,no thing happens and the report continue in the same page(no breaks)!! .I don't know why this happens ? After I decided To control the visibility through [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7346383/418343),I faced this problem.

Before this I set `PageBreakAtEnd = True` property for the table , i wanna to be the last one in the page.And it works .The page breaks.

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Pagebreak works with group's values. What is the group value for your list?

Comment: like you told me dummy `=""` :)

Comment: I wanna this list to be the last thing in the page.and any element start in a new page.

Comment: This means no page break occurs. Which are the criteria to break your report to 4 pages?

Comment: hmmm.there is a word paper which sections the required report in four pages .so i follow this paper, and i section the report in four pages using the `PageBreakAtEnd = True` property.it works with tables before the visibility control issue .but now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of **Visibility = hidden** or **visibility = expression**, page break doesn't work

To overcome this limitation:

Add a rectangle at the end of the list, not hidden, with page break at end enabled

Comment: hmmm, then is there any work ground  or idea to overcome this problem and break where i wanna to break.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help , really I'm so grateful for you.

Comment: You are welcome. Your question's made me improve my skills in reporting services!